# What should I be using here instead of ExecuteScalar?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I'm trying to return a `DbSet<Survey>` where `Survey` is defined as

```
public class Survey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Survey.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Survey.Models.Survey]'.
```

about the `DbSet<Survey> AllSurveys = (DbSet<Survey>)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` line of

```
    public DbSet<Survey> GetAllSurveys ( )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllSurveys", this._Conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        this._Conn.Open();
        DbSet<Survey> AllSurveys = (DbSet<Survey>)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        this._Conn.Close();
        return AllSurveys;
    }
```

The table in the database and the sproc I'm using were generated by

```
CREATE TABLE Surveys (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
GO
-- Create sprocs for adding, deleting, getting surveys
CREATE PROCEDURE AddSurvey
    @title NVARCHAR(100)
AS
    INSERT INTO Surveys (title) VALUES (@title)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteSurvey
    @id INT
AS
    DELETE FROM Surveys WHERE id=@id
GO
-- Seed the surveys table with 1 sample survey
EXEC AddSurvey @title = "Survey Numero Uno";

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllSurveys
AS
    SELECT * FROM SURVEYS 
        ORDER BY title ASC;
GO
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns the first cell of the first row if rows found. Else returns Null.

Comment: Since you're using `DbSet` I'm assuming you're using Entity Framework. So do you have a `Context` that you could use to call `SqlQuery` on instead of recreating a SQL connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line  `DbSet<Survey> AllSurveys = (DbSet<Survey>)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` will return an int. You can try something like:

**EDIT** Based on your comment about old school .NET. There is one more thing in your method that can be changed.

Your full method could look like this:

```
  public DbSet<Survey> GetAllSurveys ( )
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllSurveys", this._Conn)
        {
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           this._Conn.Open();
           DbSet<Survey> AllSurveys = new DbSet<Survey>();
           using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dataReader.Read())
                            {
                                Survey srv=new Survey {
                                  Id = dataReader.IsDBNull(0)?Default(int): dataReader.GetInt32(0),
                                  Title =dataReader.IsDBNull(1)?String.Empty: dataReader.GetString(1)};
                                AllSurveys.Add(srv);
                            }
                        }
           this._Conn.Close();
           return AllSurveys;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That is atrocious looking. Maybe I should consider not trying to write my app in old-school ASP.NET.

Comment: I upvote the answer but instead of `Id = int.Parse(dataReader[0].ToStrig())` I would use `Id = dataReader.GetInt32(0)`. Check the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for more.

Comment: @shadow Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: @Zippy Any idea why I'm getting an "... is inaccessible due to its protection level" on `DbSet<Survey> AllSurveys = new DbSet<Survey>();` ??

Comment: @Zippy Just added check for null values ;-)

Comment: @user5648283 probably because `Survey` is not public?